# w32-short-file-name: multi-OS user-configuration -- silence byte-compiler

Tags: byte-compilation

I have a multi-OS user-configuration.  On OSX, when I byte-compile, the function `w32-short-file-name` is not defined (which is okay).  What is the proper way to silence the byte-compiler for this message which will not affect the ability to use this user-configuration on Windows?

```
In end of data:
lawlist-dired.el:13754:1:Warning: the following functions are not known to be defined:
  w32-using-nt (3046),
  w32-short-file-name (370674)
```

[I am assuming I can apply the same answer to `w32-using-nt`.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `declare-function` to declare the files where the functions are defined. From <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`declare-function`<kbd>RET</kbd>.

> Tell the byte-compiler that function FN is defined, in FILE.
>   Optional ARGLIST is the argument list used by the function.
>   The FILE argument is not used by the byte-compiler, but by the
>   ‘check-declare’ package, which checks that FILE contains a
>   definition for FN.  ARGLIST is used by both the byte-compiler
>   and ‘check-declare’ to check for consistency.